# Matrix multiply in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I created a function to multiply a matrix by itself which gets 2 parameters, one is the matrix, the other one is an `int n`. The problem is that I cant figure out where should I use the `n` in my code so that it multiplies the matrix by itself an `n` number of times (in other words `matrix^n`). At current stage it only does `matrix^2`;

```java
public static int[][] lungimeDrumuri(int[][] array, int n) {
    int[][] newArray = new int[array.length][array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
                sum += array[i][x] * array[x][j];
            }
            newArray[i][j] = sum;
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a third for loop that goes from `1 < k < n` . You will need to remain `array` untouched in order to maintain the values of the initial matrix, will also need a matrix `newArray` to keep the values of the previous multiplication and a temporary matrix `tmp` that just hold values during the multiplication itself and then is copied to `newArray`.
Take a look in the sample below.

**FULL CODE**

```java
public static int[][] lungimeDrumuri(int[][] array, int n) {
    int[][] newArray = new int[array.length][array.length];
    // Just holds values during multiplication between two matrices
    int[][] tmp = new int[array.length][array.length];
    
    // Initialize newArray to be equal to array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            newArray[i][j] = array[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Outer loop that multiplies as many times as you want
    for (int k = 1; k < n; k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
                    sum += newArray[i][x] * array[x][j]; // Use newArray here
                }
                tmp[i][j] = sum;
            }
        }
        // Copy the result from multiplication to newArray and restart tmp
        System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, newArray, 0, tmp.length);
        tmp = new int[array.length][array.length];
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `newArray` to be equal to array, then
add a loop around the matrix multiplication and use `newArray` in your nested loops: multiply `newArray` by array.

```java
public static int[][] lungimeDrumuri(int[][] array, int n) {
    int[][] newArray = new int[array.length][array.length];
    // Add loops to initialize newArray to array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            newArray[i][j] = array[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {   // Add this loop
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
                    sum += newArray[i][x] * array[x][j];  // Use newArray here
                }
                newArray[i][j] = sum;
            }
        }
    } // and this
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int array[][] = new int[2][2];
        array[0][0] = 1;
        array[0][1] = 2;
        array[1][0] = 3;
        array[1][1] = 4;
        int newArray[][] = new int[2][2];
        //initialize array with these elements
        newArray[0][0] = 1;
        newArray[0][1] = 0;
        newArray[1][0] = 0;
        newArray[1][1] = 1;
        int n = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            newArray = lungimeDrumuri(array, newArray, i);
        }
    }

    public static int[][] lungimeDrumuri(int[][] array, int newArray[][], int n) {
        int newArray1[][] = new int[array.length][array.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
                    sum += array[i][x] * newArray[x][j];
                }
                newArray1[i][j] = sum;
            }
        }
        return newArray1;
    }
}
```

Hope this one will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two methods for clarity: the first to multiply a square matrix, and the second to call the first `n` number of times.

```java
public static int[][] lungimeDrumuri(int[][] array, int n) {
    int[][] newArray = array;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        newArray = squareMatrixMultiplication(newArray);
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

```java
public static int[][] squareMatrixMultiplication(int[][] array) {
    int[][] newArray = new int[array.length][array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
                newArray[i][j] += array[i][x] * array[x][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```